How would an ancient Chinese necromancer delay their zombies from rotting?
During the Xi dynasty of Ancient China, Zhang Xianzhong was able to gain powers to resurrect and control the dead after accidentally reading a mysterious string of words. Essentially, he's a necromancer. His resurrected zombies are animated by being supernaturally controlled like puppets. Because of this, his zombies are still rotting. To further add, the zombies work better and are easier to control the "fleshier" it is. Because of his power, he and his zombies are unable to go outside the landmass of China.
Under these specific historical conditions, is there a way for him to delay his zombies from rotting as much as possible?

You have undefined magic in your world. Why wouldn't that solve your problem? There's a difference between "preserving meat" (Pelinore's answer) and keeping flesh-in-use supple and undamaged and it's all scientifically pointless if you don't have working circulatory and nervous systems (kinda basic problems for dead zombies). So it seems you're asking for technobabble... unless you can explain the details of your problem (e.g., how do I keep dead muscles working, the answer of course is "you can't." Science is a ruthless task master.)

They'd pickle them in vinegar and mustard seed.

I agree with @JBH's comment. You have established a world in which dead people can be resurrected without more detail than "by accident", yet you want a realistic way of protecting meat from going bad? It would be like having the last part of each Indiana Jones being his correspondence with IRS and university's bureaucracy to get his travel expenses paid (althought in some of the last movies that could become the more interesting part).

Maybe this is part of this Stack's culture (I don't hang out here much), but I'm surprised to see people saying "you already have magic - use more of it" as frame challenge. I find it impressive and immersive when Fantasy/Sci-Fi uses as little "handwavium" as possible - minimizing the number of suspensions of disbelief, and keeping the rest of the world consistent and well-considered. "A Wizard Did It With Magic" works, but is less satisfying than finding a way for a wizard to do "the rest" with science. Presumably the OP knows that they can invoke more Magic, but wants to avoid doing so.

@scubbo Dmyt is asking us to crowbar science into a question about magic. We've actually had complaints in Meta about these kinds of questions because the "as real as possible" craze is getting tiresome. Dmyt isn't asking how to preserve meat. He/she is asking how to keep dead muscles acting like living muscles. If you want a science-based answer, you need to deal with science-based reality. Dead is dead. If magic was used to overcome the reality of science, then magic must be used to continue to overcome the reality of science.

"Dmyt isn't asking how to preserve meat" - and yet, if someone were to answer the question as if they were (as Pelinore and others did), the answers would have been exactly as satisfactory.
That said, if there are complaints within the community of this type of question is not enjoyable to answer, then that's a good-enough reason to preserve the community in the way it wishes to be.

[Checks notes..]
[Yes, I have notes, I've considered the topic before]
Salt..
Sugar..
Alcohol,.
Vinegar..
Honey..
Resin (from certain trees, pine would be be one, cherry is another)..
Garlic..
Lavender..
Cloves..
Crushed almonds (of the 'non-edible' varieties with much higher cyanide content)..
Etc.
All of these things have preservative properties that should help stave off spoiling, decomposition and the ravages of small insect pests, and most (if not all?) should be available in China.
[Pauses to ponder..]
[Considers the possibility he may have given this too much prior thought to be considered normal]
[Shrugs]
So take your pick..
You might consider throwing in lemon zest (just for the scent really but citric acid also inhibits the growth of molds and bacteria) mixing the whole lot into a paste & applying liberally inside and out (pump it into its veins and fill its stomach, when preserving meat it's normally best to remove the guts, where so much bacteria lives, asap, so that leaves you plenty of space to stuff some of your preservative glop to let it infuse the surrounding flesh) with occasional fresh external application.
..
You might also consider smoke drying him.. but I think that's going to leave him a bit less flexible, perhaps prone to cracks & fractures in the skin when he moves? 

"I love the smell of smoked zombies in the morning" (cit.)

@L.Dutch "Smoke me a zombie, I'll be back for breakfast" (Ace Rimmer, alternate dark-reality version)

Tar would be both cheap and effective as well. It would make the zombies more flammable though.

@GoingDurden "flammable" blazing zombies!? Sounds good  a few of those charging in like cut price berserkers should help break up most military formations nicely ..  .. now, if we strap a sealed keg of gunpowder to them, once the wood burns through they can blow up in the middle of the enemy as well  .. tar is good for helping to give an anoxic environment  though the resins applied as part of an external 'skin lotion' should do that too.

@Pelinore, you do not need to strap a keg of gunpowder to them, just put a bag of the stuff inside their belly, replacing their useless guts. Add some shrapnel for extra fun!

@GoingDurden well if the keg of powder is going inside them (they've no use for those lungs either, toss them out too, plenty of space for a small to mid size keg then) strap the shrapnel on their bodies, doubles as armour (until they blow up) then.

Camphor has some significant anti-bacterial properties and is widely used in Traditional Chinese Medicine.

I love the idea of lemon-scented zombies.

Coating corpses in honey was a way to embalm them and delay decomposition, or more simply to prevent wound to get infected. And the mellified man is known Chinese legend.
Your necromancer can use such a method. For sure zombies won't get annoyed by the insect that the honey covering their bodies will attract.

They could get the honey from the hives and apply it themselves.  They wouldn't mind being stung.

Could be an issue. Wasps and other insects might lay their eggs in this figurative treasure trove, and those will eat the corpse in short order.

@user2962533 wasps defended zombies?! That's the non plus ultra. Try chopping the head of a zombie while yellow striped psychos buzz around you,,,

It would be kind of funny: Alice: "Do, do I smell.... Honey?!", Bob: "OH SHIT"

a honey glazed corpse would be a nice snack for a bear though.

Rusting copper with sulfur- its an anti-biotic, anti-herbicide, anti-fungicide, anti-everything. Put the corpse into a tank of the stuff, lett it drench, till its darkgreenblue and basically unable to rot on its own.
Another idea is, to have the corpse fermented- as in you grow beneficial bacteria on it, whos byproducts kill all follow up creatures. Welcome to the army zombie soy-sauce factory. The workers are inside the pots..
Finally- dry and replace the water inside the corpse with something else - oily.. that way, there is just nothing there for the bacterria to life on, the zombies will become rancid, but the lower layers are good for another thousand years.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adipocere
Have fun. They will walk it off.

Would that be copper sulphate CuSO4?

Copper sulfate would be rather expensive, I would go with iron acetate as a substitute. It would kill the bacteria, tan the zombie, dry it out a bit and dye it pitch black, to make it even more terrifying.

@GoingDurden 'Price' is relative to supply and availability, sulphur and copper might both be 'reasonably' (for a given value of reasonably) cheap and easy to come by if you're in the right place .. I have no idea what deposits of each china has where however

Sylvanite and cinnabar.
According to this paper, "metalloantimicrobial efficacy (toxicity to bacteria) from 100’s of nanomolar concentrations are tellurium as TeO3 2−: mercury, Hg2+; silver, Ag+, gold, Au3+..."  We'll get the tellurium, silver, and gold from "the Dashuigou and Majiagou gold–tellurium epithermal vein deposits", while the cinnabar was widely used in Chinese alchemy, coming perhaps from "the mountains of Sichuan and Hunan provinces in central China.".  I'm thinking we'll say it is sylvanite in the deposits (AgAuTe2); the tellurium might be processed into (TeO3)2- by heating it in the presence of oxygen.  The combination of these things (perhaps with some arsenic, copper, etc. added) bears much in common with a xian immortality elixir.  We can use it once to kill the zombie and once to preserve its lifespan!  But the zombies so created are expensive, being impregnated with silver and gold.

Make the source of your zombies just braindead corpses (asphyxiating living people?), keeping all the rest of the bodily functions... functional. If the necromancer can make them walk and bite, should be able to make them beat and breath once their brain flatlined. This way they'll be as fleshy as they'll ever be.

Coat (and bake) them in terracotta. Magic will keep the undead body functioning long enough for the terracotta to soak up its properties during the process, so the envelope itself will move and react to the orders. As a side benefit, this will make the zombies hardened and more durable. And terracotta will last for millennia, long after the necromancer passes away (and the zombies will remain motionless and inert without explicit orders).
In fact, something similar was used as a subplot in a certain movie.
